# Implement Global interfaces

Tags: delphi, dll, interface

I'm currently struggling with the following:

I need to create two different DLL's, which do exactly the same but are looking to a different DB. The two DB's are nothing alike.

My dll's should be handling the communication with those different DB's.
So that the main program chooses which dll he wants to use.

I want to be sure each dll has exactly the same procudes/functions/...
I was thinking of using interfaces. 
But I can't figure out how to create global interfaces. the dll's belong to the same projectgroup.

Comment: I cannot understand the question. What notification mechanism are you referring to?

Comment: the notification isn't that important. My main goal is to create an interface, that i can implement in different dll's.  the dll's belong to the same projectgroup

Comment: If it's not important, remove it. And replace it with text that can help us understand your problem. Perhaps you want a single common unit that defines interfaces that is used by both of your DLLs. But I'm having to guess.

Comment: That's what i need, but i can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: apart from the interface, why *two different DLLs, which do exactly the same* when you can use one which accepts the DB config in a procedure or reads some config parameters from a text file instead? It seems bad design to me. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: 1. Create a unit. 2. Add the interface declarations. 3. Include that unit in both DLL projects.

Comment: but if you need to add something, you need to change it in all dll's? is there a way you can declare this global in your projectgroup, and the dll's in the projectgroup can use it?

Comment: fantaghirocc: they do exactly the same externally but the calculations inside are so fundamentally different, it would be better to work with two different dll's

Comment: Do exactly as I said in my last comment.

Comment: @Hanne: The interface is defined in one unit. If it must be changed, then you modify it in that one unit, modify the implenting classes in your DLLs and recompile your DLLs. Note that you should only change interfaces during development, It is not a good idea to change them after you published them. To make changes, define a new interface that is based on the previous one.

Comment: Presenting a common interface to multiple databases is exactly what ODBC is for. Delphi can consume ODBC. So, are you sure you actually need to do what you plan to do? It sounds like it's a solved problem.

Comment: Define a com component with methods in its interface, you can then create a second com component implementing the same methods. Delphi does this easily

Answer (score 1):

I do believe you're making a "mountain out of a molehill" thinking you need 2 different DLLs. But if you choose the last of my suggested options, you should find it fairly easy to switch between a 2 DLL solution and 1 DLL solution.

## Option 1

This is the most straightforward:

- Create a new unit.
- Add your DLL interface (the exports).
- Include the unit in both projects.

  unit DllExportIntf;

  interface

  uses
    DllExportImpl;

  exports DoX;

  implementation

  end.

Note that this unit uses `DllExportImpl` which will also have to be included in both projects. However, you'll need 2 different files with the same name in 2 different locations in your file system. So each DLL project will have different implementations.

Now whenever you make a change to your interface, your projects won't compile until you've updated each of the `DllExportImpl` units.

What I don't particularly like about this solution is the need for units with the same name but different behaviour. Since you intend having both DLLs in the same project group: I should warn you that I've experienced the IDE getting confused by duplicate unit names.

## Option 2

Place the exports into a shared include file.

```
library DllSharedExportsImpl1;

uses
  DllExportImpl1 in 'DllExportImpl1.pas';

{$I ..\Common\DllExports.inc}
```

The DllExports.inc file will only include your exports clauses. E.g.

```
exports DoX;
```

This has the advantage that now each DLL can use different unit names for the different implementations. And if you change your include file, neither project will compile until you've updated its implementation unit to accommodate the change.

Note that this does come with its own set of problems. The way includes work: the compiler effectively shoves the contents of the include file into the unit at compile time. So what looks like line 7 to the IDE is entirely different to the compiler. Also editing include files can be a bit of a nuisance because context can only be determined where the file is included making editor support quite impractical.

## Option 3

This option is a little more work, but provides much better long-term maintainability.

You do this by implementing your interface via polymorphic objects. In this way, both DllProjects will also share the routines that are actually exported. When each DLL initialises, it sets the concrete implementation to be used.

Your DLL interface could look something like this.

```
unit DllExportIntf;

interface

type
  TAbstractImpl = class(TObject)
  public
    procedure DoX; virtual; abstract;
  end;

procedure AssignDllImpl(const ADllImpl: TAbstractImpl);

procedure DoX;
exports DoX;

implementation

var
  GDllImpl: TAbstractImpl;

procedure AssignDllImpl(const ADllImpl: TAbstractImpl);
begin
  if Assigned(GDllImpl) then
  begin
    GDllImpl.Free;
  end;
  GDllImpl := ADllImpl;
end;

procedure DoX;
begin
  GDllImpl.DoX;
end;

end.
```

When you initialise your DLL, you can call:

```
AssignDllImpl(TDllImpl_1.Create);
```

A clear advantage of this approach is that if there is any common code between your 2 DLLs, it can be included in your base implementation. Also, if you can change an existing method DLL in such a way that it does not require a change to `TAbstractImpl`, you possibly will only need to recompile your DLLs.

Furthermore, if you need to change existing virtual abstract methods, you will have to update the overrides in your concrete implementations accordingly.

> **WARNING** If you add a new virtual abstract method, your projects will still compile with warnings that you are creating objects with abstract methods. However, you ***should always treat warnings as errors***. If you do, this caveat won't be a problem.

---

*NOTE*: As mentioned earlier, using this approach you should be able to fairly easily switch between single DLL and 2 DLL solutions. The difference basically boils down to which units are included in the project, and how you initialise the global.

It may also be worthwhile mentioning that you could even eliminate the global altogether by implementing a `Handle` to use with each of your DLL routines. (Similar to Windows.) *Bear in mind that there are technical issues when trying to pass objects between DLL and application code. This is why instead of passing objects, you use a "handles" to objects and encapsulate the actual object instances internally.*

Comment: Option 1 isn't what I suggested at all

Answer (score 1):

Considering all that was said, I believe that you would be more successful if you design your solution with *packages*, not DLLs. A package is a DLL, but rich in symbols, so Delphi can be a better use of it. Particularly, the symbols declared inside the package will more easily be loaded by your application, with a much higher level of abstraction. It´s what the Delphi IDE uses to load components.

So, following this design, this is what you have to do:

Declare your interfaces in units existing in a *package* named (for instance) `DBServices.dpk`. Here is an example of such an unit:

```
unit DBService1;

interface

uses
  ....;

type
  IService1 = interface
    [....]  // here goes the GUID
    procedure ServiceMethod1;
    procedure ServiceMethod2;
    // and so on...
  end;

implementation

end.
```

So, above you created an unit that declares an interface. Your aplication can use that interface anywhere, just reference the package in your application and use it in other units and you will have the access to the symbols declared.

Declare the implementation class for that very same interface in another unit of another package, for instance, dedicated to SQLServer (`SQLServerServices.dpk`):

```
unit SQLServerService1;

interface

uses
  DBService1, ....;

type
  TSQLServerService1 = class(TInterfacedObject, IService1)
  protected // IService1
    procedure ServiceMethod1;
    procedure ServiceMethod2;
    // and so on...
  end;

implementation

procedure TSQLServerService.ServiceMethod1;
begin
  // Specific code for SQL Server
end;

procedure TSQLServerService.ServiceMethod2;
begin
  // Specific code for SQL Server
end;

...

end.
```

Above you declared an implementing class for the interface `IService1`. Now you have two packages, one declaring the interfaces and other implementing those interfaces. Both will be consumed by your application. If you have more implementations for the same interfaces, add other packages dedicated to them.

One important thing is: you have to have a factory system. A factory system is a procedure ou class that will create and return the implementations for your application from each package.

So, in terms of code, in each service package (the ones that implement the interfaces) add a unit named, for instance, `xxxServiceFactories`, like this:

```
unit SQLServerServiceFactories;

interface

uses
  DBService1;

function NewService1: IService1;

implementation

uses
  SQLServerService1;

function NewService1: IService1;
  Result := TSQLServerService1.Create;
end;

end.
```

The code above declares a function that creates the SQL Server implementation and returns it as an interface. Now, if you call a method from the interface returned, you will be actually calling the specific implementation of it for SQL Server.

After loading the package, you will have to link to that function in the very same way you would do if working if a DLL. After you have the pointer for the function, you can call it and you will have the interface in your application's code:

```
...
var
  service1: IService1;
begin
  service1 := NewService1;

  service1.ServiceMethod1; // here, calling your method!
end;
```

The model I described in this answer is the one I used in a similar scenario I had to deal with in the past. I presented general ideas that work, but you have to understand the fundamentals of packages and interfaces to really master the technique.

A comprehensive explanation on those matters would be very long for an answer here, but I guess it will be a good starting point for you!

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is create a COM component project. Define your methods on that & implementations for one DB.  Then create a second COM component that uses the same interface.

Answer (score 0):

On the off-chance that your question is more about the fundamentals of Delphi, I've added another answer which may be more helpful to you than the first one. My first answer focused on getting 2 DLLs to expose the same methods (as per the main body of your question). This one focuses on the last 2 sentences of your question:

> But I can't figure out how to create global interfaces. The dll's belong to the same project group.

Based on this, it sounds like you're looking for an option to "mark an interface as global so that projects in the same group can use them". Delphi doesn't need a special feature to do this because it's trivially available if you understand certain fundamental principles.

When you create a new unit, it is by default added to the current project. However if you want to share the unit between multiple projects, it's a good idea to save it to a different folder so it's easy to see that it's shared. Your first DLLs project file should look something like this.

```
library Dll1;

uses
  DllSharedIntf in '..\Common\DllSharedIntf.pas';
```

You can define your "global" interface in the `DllSharedIntf` unit. E.g.

```
unit DllSharedIntf;

interface

type
  IDllIntf = interface
    ['{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}']
    procedure DoX;
  end;

implementation

end.
```

NOTE: Because the *interface type* is declared in the *interface section* of the unit, it is considered "global" because other units are able to use it. But this doesn't automatically make it available to other projects.

You now have to add the shared unit to your other project so it becomes available for use by other units in that project. To do this:

- Activate Dll2
- Select `Project` and `Add to Project...`
- Find `DllSharedIntf` and add it.

Delphi will automatically update your project source file to include the unit.

```
library Dll2;

uses
  DllSharedIntf in '..\Common\DllSharedIntf.pas';
```

Now in each DLL project you can add a separate implementation unit. E.g. For Dll1:

```
unit DllImpl1;

interface

uses
  //It's very important to indicate that this unit uses the shared unit.
  //Otherwise you won't be able to access the "global types" declared
  //in the interface-section of that unit.
  DllSharedIntf;

type
  TDllImpl1 = class(TInterfacedObject,
      //Any types defined in the interface-section of any units that
      //this unit **uses**, can be accessed as if they were declared
      //in this unit.
      IDllIntf)
  protected
    //The fact that this class is marked as implementing the IDllIntf
    //means that the compiler will insist on you implementing all 
    //methods defined in that interface-type.
    procedure DoX;
  end;

implementation
```

> **NOTE** This answer only covers sharing an interface between projects. You'll still need to expose the functionality of the DLLs via appropriate exports. You'll need an approach similar to option 3 of my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31891696/224704).

## Summary

We don't usually talk about "global interfaces" in Delphi. It's generally understood that anything declared in the interface section of a unit is globally accessible. (*We do make more of an issue about **global variables** due to their dangers though; but that's an entirely different topic.*)

In Delphi:

- Whenever you want one unit (A) to make use of functionality defined in another unit (B), you need to add unit B to the **uses** clause of unit A.
- Whenever you want a project to use a unit created in another project, you need to add the unit to the project. (*TIP: It's a good idea to put such units in a separate folder.*)

NOTE: When sharing units between projects, the project group is actually irrelevant. Projects don't need to be in the same group to share units. All you need to do is ensure the project can *access* the unit so that other units in your project can **uses** it.